# Persian text in url Django

Tags: django, url, iis, unicode, arabic

I have some links that include Persian texts, such as:

```bash
http://sample.com/fields/طب%20نظامی
```

And in the view function I want to access to Persian part, so:

```py
url = request.path_info
key = re.findall('/fields/(.+)', url)[0]
```

But I get the following error:

```bash
IndexError at /fields/
list index out of range
```

Actually, the problem is with the index zero because it can not see anything there! It should be noted that it is a Django project on ***IIS Server*** and I have successfully tested it with other servers and the local server. I think it has some thing related to IIS. Moreover I have tried to slugify the url without success. I can encode urls successfully, but I think it is not the actual answer to this question.

Based on the comments:
I checked the `request.path` too and the same problem. It contains:

```bash
/fields/
```

I implemented a sample django project in local server and here is my views:

```py
def test(request):
   t = request.path
   return HttpResponse(t)
```

The results:

```bash
http://127.0.0.1:8000/تست/
/تست/
```

Without any problem.

Based on the @sytech comment, I have created a middlware.py in my app directory:

```
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

class SimpleMiddleware(WSGIHandler):

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        print(environ['UNENCODED_URL'])
        return super().__call__(environ, start_response)
```

and in `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'apps.middleware.SimpleMiddleware',
]
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'start_response'
```

Comment: Are you sure it is in `path_info`? Can you share the `path`/`url` that you used here?

Comment: The path_info contains /fields/.

Comment: It is not there and it is my problem. Maybe my question was not appropriate, with the phrase "it can not see it".

Comment: well likely you first visit the page with `fields/` hence the error, and only later will visit `fields/some-persian-text`

Comment: How is it possible? because it is just a link that i produce and nothing most. Also, please note that i can access the same way with local server.

Comment: if you specify `print(re.findall('/fields/(.+)', url))` so wiithout indexing, do you see that every now and then it contains data written in Persian?

Comment: Please note that as i said in the first comment the path and the path_info does not contain the Persian text. The main problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237467/discussion-between-keramat-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: What version of IIS and what version of URLrewrite are you using? Are you using wfastcgi or something else to run the python app? I'm also assuming you're using Python3 and a modern version of Django, like 3.x or 4.x right?

Comment: IIS version is 10.0.20348.1. URLrewrite version is 7.2.1993. Yes is use wfastcgi. python version is 3.8.5 and Django version is 3.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using python `split()` method

```
url = "http://sample.com/fields/طب%20نظامی"
url_key = url.split(sep="/", maxsplit=4)
url_key[-1]
output : 'طب%20نظامی'
```

in this url is splited by **`/`** which occurs 4 time in string so it will return a list like this

```
['http:', '', 'sample.com', 'fields', 'طب%20نظامی']
```

then extract result like this `url_key[-1]` from `url_key`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have another problem in your rewrite configuration, on IIS, depending on your rewrite configuration, you may need to access this through the [`UNENCODED_URL` variable](https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/url-rewrite-v2-1) which will contain the unencoded value.

This can be demonstrated in a simple WSGI middleware:

```py
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

class MyHandler(WSGIHandler):
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        print(environ['UNENCODED_URL'])
        return super().__call__(environ, start_response)
```

You would see the unencoded URL and the path part that's in Persian would be passed `%D8%B7%D8%A8%2520%D9%86%D8%B8%D8%A7%D9%85%DB%8C`. Which you can then decode with `urllib.parse.unquote`

```py
urllib.parse.unquote('%D8%B7%D8%A8%2520%D9%86%D8%B8%D8%A7%D9%85%DB%8C')
# طب%20نظامی
```

If you wanted, you could use a middleware to set this as an attribute on the `request` object or even override the `request.path_info`.

You must be using URL rewrite v7.1.1980 or higher for this to work.

You could also use the `UNENCODED_URL` directly in the rewrite rule, but that may result in headaches with routing.

> I can encode urls successfully, but I think it is not the actual answer to this question.

Yeah, that is another option, but may result in other issues like this: [IIS10 URL Rewrite 2.1 double encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47146029/5747944)

Comment: I am using the default configuration of rewrite.

Comment: super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

Comment: @keramat this is a `__call__` method, not `__init__` not sure how you've got that error from the above. Also I'm not sure what you mean by "default" configuration. What is the version of IIS and what is the version of the module?

Comment: IIS version is 10.0.20348.1. URLrewrite version is 7.2.1993. Yes is use wfastcgi. python version is 3.8.5 and Django version is 3.2.3.

Comment: I have edited the question with some new information.

Comment: @keramat I don't think you're using the handler correctly. As an alternative, you should also just be able to see the variable in `request.META` like `request.META['UNENCODED_URL']` -- your IIS site configuration might need to allow this variable to be passed to the application (I don't remember if it's available by default).

Comment: thanks for your reply. What is wrong with the handler usage? Also, please note that I already tried request.META['UNENCODED_URL'] which returned empty again. I will try to find the IIS confing you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

you can Split the URL by :

```
string = http://sample.com/fields/طب%20نظامی
last_part = string. Split("/")[-1]
print(last_part)
output :< طب%20نظامی >


slugify(last_part)

or

slugify(last_part, allow_unicode=True)
```

I guess This Will Help You :)

Comment: No, It is not the answer to problem.